# EC2 Windows Licence

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need 5 Windows on t2.medium VPS-es, I will use 12 hours / week each one, and when I calculate using amazon simply calculator it says: 
Estimate of your Monthly Bill ($ 35.08)

Is this true? do I need to pay extra windows licence?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/):

> Pre-configured Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) enable you to start
>   running fully supported Windows Server virtual machine instances in
>   minutes. You can choose between a number of server operating system
>   versions and whether or not you want to include SQL Server. **When you
>   use AMIs, Microsoft software licensing is handled by AWS and included
>   in your monthly bill.** For other licensing options, and details about
>   how to run other Microsoft software on AWS, visit the Microsoft
>   License Mobility page.

So if you plan on [using a windows AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/finding-an-ami.html), the licensing cost is wrapped into the price per instance-hour of running the EC2 instance. This is the standard route if you are hoping to simply use virtual machines with Windows installed.

Also note that you may incur fees for network in/out and [EBS (persistent storage volumes)](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/), depending on your traffic and if your instances are configured to use EBS.

Comment: I'm not that good in english, so I will pay only 35$ / month? (in calculator I added 30gb ebs for every server too)?

Comment: not always, there are always some extra fee waiting for you, when you start using aws.